# Where newest date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to match and set records from one table to another. There are two where clauses that I need. If account is "A" and if DateLastModified is the most recent (newest) date.

> ```
> Example John Smith DatelastModified = 1/1/2017
>         John Smith DatelastModified = 9/24/19 
> I would only want it to match to the John Smith with the date of 9/24/19
> ```

```
Update p
Set p.custom1 = p2.custom1       
FROM PatientDemographics AS p INNER JOIN PatientDemo2 AS p2 
ON
 p.FirstName = p2.FirstName and
 p.LastName = p2.LastName  and 
 p.DateofBirth = p2.DateofBirth and
 p.ZipCode = p2.ZipCode
where p.AccountStatus = 'A'
and DateLastModified is ?
```

Comment: What table does `DateLastModified` come from?

Comment: PatientDemographics table

Comment: You could try:   and p.DateLastModified = MAX(p.DateLastModified)

Comment: Getting this message now. "An aggregate may not appear in the WHERE clause unless it is in a subquery contained in a HAVING clause or a select list, and the column being aggregated is an outer reference."

Answer (score 0):

Using window functions you can pick the most recent record to update for each combination of first+last+dob+zip (I'm assuming this identifies the patient), like this:

```
;WITH PatientsByDateLastModified AS
(
    SELECT *
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FirstName, LastName, DateofBirth, ZipCode
                                  ORDER BY DateLastModified DESC) AS RN
      FROM PatientDemographics
)
UPDATE patients
   SET patients.custom1 = demo.custom1
  FROM PatientsByDateLastModified patients
 INNER
  JOIN PatientDemo2 demo
    ON patients.FirstName = demo.FirstName
   AND patients.LastName = demo.LastName
   AND patients.DateofBirth = demo.DateofBirth
   AND patients.ZipCode = demo.ZipCode
 WHERE patients.AccountStatus = 'A'
   AND patients.RN = 1 -- this makes sure only the most recent row gets updated
```